# How to draw different shapes on an image in openCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am a beginner in OpenCV. I know C++ and Android Programming. I have decided to shift on OpenCV. 
In my project, Using OpenCV I am detecting a red color ball through camera and getting its coordinates. Using these coordinates, I want to draw the same line or shape on a separate white image. For example, if the use user moves ball to write the alphabet W in the air, and I have received all the coordinates of ball position, I want to draw W on the separate image. I am not asking for code, but little help and guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#circle(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Point,%20int,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar)  look there for line(), rectange(), etc, too.  [c++ version](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html)

Comment: If you have all the coordinates couldn't you just change the number (i.e colour) of the corresponding value in the seperate matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the coordinates it is easy. First create your cv::Mat and set it all white.

```
cv::Mat image;
image.setTo(cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
```

Then if you have the begin and the end coordinates you can draw a line using opencv [line](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) function.

```
cv::line(image, cv::Point(initial_coords.x, initial_coords.y), cv::Point(end_coords.x, end_coords.y), cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
```

Finally to do the w use [puttext function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext)

```
cv::putText(image, "text", cv::Point(coords.x, coords.y), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 2, Scalar::all(255), 3,8);
```

If you need to erase the window before adding new things use again the

```
image.setTo(cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
```